# Qtable in python size issues

Tags: python, qt, qtablewidget

I'm working with python and qt.
I created a table and put some item in.
there is a column that appear when i insert a row in my table. this column is 1,2,3,4 it depend of the number of the row. it is a verticalheader but i can't control the size of this column.
I woud like to control eveything in my Qtable

Answer (score 0):

Look at the commands setSectionResizeMode(), setVisible(), etc [in the QTableWidget docs.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html)

Also, use the program called Qt Designer and then "view code" to see your changes.